# Interrupted WPF animation is much slower in the reverse direction

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Here's my code:

XAML:

```
  <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Padding="10" Name="cmdGrow" Click="cmdGrow_Click" Height="40" Width="160"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Grow Button #1 "></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Padding="10" Name="cmdShrink" Click="cmdShrink_Click"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Shrink Button #1"></Button>

    </Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace Animation
{
    public partial class CodeAnimation : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public CodeAnimation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cmdGrow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            widthAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            widthAnimation.To = 270;

            cmdGrow.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
        }

        private void cmdShrink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DoubleAnimation widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            widthAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            //widthAnimation.To = 20;

            cmdGrow.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
        }
    } 
}
```

Resulting in the following simple UI:

[image]

In the cmdShrink_Click() event, if the "To" attribute of the animation is not specified, the reverse animation (i.e. the "shrink") is way slower than the forward (i.e. "grow") animation.  I have checked the Duration attribute by placing a breakpoint within the cmdShrink_click() event, and it shows up as 5 seconds:

[image]

To repro, click the grow button, than click the shrink button halfway through **before the grow animation completes**.

It's as if the durations of multiple animations are having a cumulative effect.

I am on Windows 7, .NET FW 4 Client Profile, VS 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is slower because it has to cover a smaller size difference in the same amount of time (5 seconds).  The growth animation's rate was based on its expected end size, but you cut the animation short.  If you stop the growth animation halfway through, then the distance the shrinking animation needs to cover is half of what the growth animation *expected* to cover, but you're still telling it to take a full five seconds.  To cover the half the distance in the same amount of time, it proceeds at half the speed.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it!  Initially, I really did not take the time to understand what "Duration" was.  This is what happens when you work from ready-made projects!  Will accept as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: I am happy to be the one that pushed you over 8K, congratulations and many thanks.